# Survey Database Design with Repeating Groups

Tags: database-design, conditional-statements, survey, repeat

I have a simple survey database where a linear set of questions are asked. The database is set up below.

```
Survey Table
id: PK
(other details)

Question Table
id: PK
survey_id: FK
(other details)

Response Table
id: PK
question_id: FK
(other details)
```

I have been asked to modify the survey to allow N repeating question groups. For example.

1. What is your name? What is your address?
2. Do you play a sport?
3. What sport do you play?
4. What position do you play?
5. Do you play another sport? *If yes go to 3 else go to 6*
6. (Additional Questions)

What would be the best way to design a survey database with repeating groups?

I have thought about using a question rule table to direct the line of questions. For example.

```
Question Rule Table
id: PK
question_id: FK
response_validation_rule (possibly a regex pattern)
next_question_id
```

Would this be the best way to implement the repeating groups question? I am also guessing it will be difficult to normalize the data as well. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self many-to-many relation in Question Table may helps. 
The many-to-many relation will relate a question to other questions. 

To achieve the criteria to fetch related questions:

> If yes go to 3

Could be done by adding a FK from answer table to many-to-many table.
Something like this:
[image]

I just suggest not to use surrogate identifier column in Related-Question table.

- The composite PK will be `{main question id, related question id,answer id}`
- Check constraint will be `{main question id <> related question id}`

Comment: Thank you very much for such a complete reply. For the answer table, how would open ended questions be dealt with?

Comment: You are welcome. I think you should have a question-count column on Survey table, then having a question-number column in Question table with a checking mechanism (trigger or application logic)  to check if question-number <= question-count will helps.